# Save a file with fs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fs

Here's the problem: I have an API which takes a json value and writes it in a file with the name of the length of the files in the directory. I'm using the fs module and it works correctly but the app isn't able to read it because fs.writeFile doesnt save it. Infact, if I go to the file and save it with ctrl+s it works fine. How can I force the code to save the contents of the file in it?

Here's the portion of code:

```
  path = path.concat(`/${files.length + 1}.json`);
  fs.writeFile(path, json, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("Results Received"); // if there is an error
  });
});
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Is the callback in writeFile called? What does it output? This bit of code isn't enough to diagnose anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `writeFileSync` or `fs.promises.writeFile` instead:

```
  const path = filePath.concat(`/${files.length + 1}.json`)   
  fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(json), 'utf8')
```